# Member Variable Memory across calls in swift viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

This looks obvious, but I am stumbled by how to handle memory for member variables in swift.
Here is a sample code --

```
class TwitMeTableViewController: UITableViewController{
    var userTweets:[AnyObject]!{
        didSet{
            print("?? TweetCount is \(userTweets.count)??") // 3
            updateUI()
        }
    }
    var session:TWTRSession!{
        didSet{
stTwitter.getHomeTimelineSinceID(nil, count: 30, successBlock: { (tweets) in
            self.userTweets = tweets // 2
}
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.userTweets = [] // 1
    }

     func updateUI(){
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if let tweets = userTweets{
            return tweets.count // 4
        }
        return 0
        }
}
```

As you can see, I initialise `userTweets` in viewDidLoad (`1`) and replace it when I actually get tweets(`2`).
Then there is a updateUI(`3`) call initiated in `didSet`. But at `numberOfRowsInSection`(`4`) the count results in Zero which is what when userTweets was initialised in viewDidLoad (`1`)

Can someone explain what is going on and how userTweet should be initialised and how new values should be added to same variable.
Note session is initialised when user logs in from a different screen/view.

Comment: Where does `tweets` come from at 2? Have you set a breakpoint at 2? Do you get the tweet count log twice?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You write `self.userTweets = tweets` but there is no such `tweets`, so your code cannot possibly compile. You have omitted something very important - you have not shown us your real code. So how can anyone help?

Comment: @matt more code added.

Comment: @paulw count is 30 at both //2 & //3, while 0 at both //1 & //4

Comment: You need to dispatch your tableview reload on the main queue since your network operation completion handler will be executed on a background thread. Have you confirmed that `numberOfRowsInSection` is called twice?

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate model class.

In your view controller, you get a reference to the one instance of your model class which you instantiate only once at startup time.

There are several patterns how to separate model from view, and how you get this model reference into your viewcontroller.

A very simple one would be to instantiate and hold a reference to your model in your AppDelegate. Then when you initialize your ViewController, you ask your AppDelegate for the one model instance.

There are more elegant patterns, but all have in common that you separate your model from your ViewControllers.

Comment: Hmm, I was trying to avoid model in AppDelegate. I was thinking of creating a singleton for model. Would love to get more pointers on other patterns.

Comment: Be careful to alwas hold a reference to your singleton so that you don't initialize it over and over again. Some of my apps take some time to populate the model, so I like to start a background process that does this when I'm starting the app. The important part ist to separate your model. Which pattern you use is up to you.